# How do I pass local settings?

Tags: javascript

The documentation on [Drupal.behaviours](https://www.drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#local_settings_behaviors) suggests that local settings can be passed to Drupal's JavaScript behaviors.

Rather than hard coding my series data into my function:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [1, 5, 4]
}, {
    name: 'John',
    data: [3, 1, 2]
}]
```

how can I pass this series data to my function as settings, directly after the context?

JS code (my_highcharts.js)

```
(function ($) {

Drupal.behaviors.my_highcharts = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('#drupal_behaviours').highcharts({
      chart: {
          type: 'bar'
      },
      title: {
          text: 'Drupal.behaviors'
      },
      colors: ['#50b432', '#ed561b'],
      xAxis: {
          categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Fruit eaten'
          }
      },
      series: [{
          name: 'Jane',
          data: [1, 5, 4]
      }, {
          name: 'John',
          data: [3, 1, 2]
      }]
    });
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

Module code

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_highcharts') . '/highcharts.js');
return array('#markup' => '<div id="drupal_behaviours" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing I would suggest no using #drupal_behaviours as a HTML element ID because it doesn't describe that element in any way.

It would more logically be called #chart or #highchart or something like that.

To add settings you can use [drupal_add_js()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) (there are examples on that docs page) like this (in your custom module in PHP):

```
// add the series' to a javascript setting.
$series = array(
  array(
    'name' => 'Jane',
    'data' => array(1, 5, 4),
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'data' => array(3, 1, 2),
  ),
);
drupal_add_js(array(
  'moduleName' => array(
    'series' => $series
  )
), 'setting');
```

Then in the js you can access it like this:

```
(function ($) {

Drupal.behaviors.my_highcharts = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('#drupal_behaviours').highcharts({
      chart: {
          type: 'bar'
      },
      title: {
          text: 'Drupal.behaviors'
      },
      colors: ['#50b432', '#ed561b'],
      xAxis: {
          categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Fruit eaten'
          }
      },
      series: settings.moduleName.series
    });
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

Note how the settings object in the javascript mimics what you passed into drupal_add_js().